# Is there a proof for what I describe as the "recursive process of mathematical induction for testing divisibility".

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I was working on my homework for Discrete Math, and we were asked to "Prove: $6 \mid n^{3}+5n$,where $n\in \mathbb{N}$" my solution varied significantly from how I have seen it done by others.  I noticed a pattern and used it to say "$6\mid Q(n)$ iff $Q(k+1)-Q(k)$,where $k in \mathbb{N}$, is also divisible by $6$ ∵ $Q(k+1)-Q(k)$ represents the recursive process of mathematical induction for testing divisibility."  I was not satisfied with it, even though it appears true.  Attached is a picture for better context.  But my overall question is has anyone heard of a proof that verifies the pattern I was describing, or could they come up with one?

It appears that when one subtracts $P(k)$ via the induction hypothesis from $P(k+1)$, then one is left with a new function $Q(n)$, which we know logically needs to be divisible by the target number for our proof to work. Therefore, $Q(k+1)-Q(k)$ will either yield a new function that is divisible by the term one is looking for, or will lead to a new function that logically needs to be divisible by the target number for our proof to work, and so on and so forth.
[image]

Comment: I have already fixed the errors in the bottom, so it need not be mentioned.  It was an oversight on my part.  It is supposed to read ∴ 6|P(k+1) ∵ m = q; and 6 | n^3+5n is True by P.M.I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice!

Yes that's correct, if you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ of terms which are all divisible by a fixed integer $m$, then their differences must be also. If you are trying to prove that each of the $a_i$ are divisible by $m$, then you could construct a new sequence:
\begin{align*}
b_1&=a_2-a_1 \\
b_2&=a_3-a_2 \\
b_3&=a_4-a_3 \\
\vdots
\end{align*}

and try to prove that the $b_i$ are divisible by $m$. Provided you prove that $m\mid a_1$ as well, this would mean that $a_n=a_1+b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n$ is also divisible by $m$.

In your example, this works particularly nicely, because $a_n$ is a cubic polynomial in $n$. When you calculate the the difference between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$, you get a quadratic polynomial in $n$, from which is it simpler to prove the divisibility.

In general in fact, if you have a $k$th degree polynomial $p(x)$, and you calculate the difference

$$p(x+1)-p(x)$$

the resulting polynomial will have degree $(k-1)$ (because the $x^k$ terms cancel). Using your idea you can repeatedly calculate differences, decreasing the degree of the polynomial, until you reach a constant polynomial, from which it will be trivial to calculate any divisibility.

I don't believe this has a name, but it is a relatively standard technique when trying to inductively prove divisibility of polynomials such as this one, along with factoring.

Comment: The way I have seen others do this particular problem, and the way my professor did it, was "My method was to take 3k^2+3k and format it as 3k(k+1). And since we have k(k+1) one of those two must be even, and thus divisible by 2. And since its multiplied by 3, its divisible by 6."  So this was the first time I had seen anyone solve a divisibility induction the way I did it.  Thank you for your help, I will work on trying to better understand it now.  *Grins *

Comment: Yup, and in that case its slightly faster. Your way is more general though, as there is not always an obvious factorisation which can help you prove it. If you learn about modular arithmetic in the future, you can actually show quite easily, that it suffices to check that it is true for the first $m$ values of the sequence (if it is a polynomial like this one), when you are testing for divisibility by $m$.